# Python - How to define a another library source

Tags: python, pip, package, python-import

I'm new in Python and I have knowledge of R. Due to admin-restriction I can't install packages in folder
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib

Now, I'm wondering if I can install the package in a folder
C:\libPython

and considering this folder when I import the library. So, there are two tasks to carry out:

1. Install a package into C:\libPython
2. To "inform" python that there is apart from the standard library source another source C:\libPython.

In R both steps are done by defining the new path:

```
myLib <- "C:/libR"
.libPaths(myRLib)
install.packages("somewhat", lib=myRLib)
library(somewhat)
```

I'm using Windows 7 and 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install the package you can use `--target` command

```
pip install --target=C:\Lib package_name
```

> `--target dir`
>
> Install packages into dir. By default this will not replace existing
>   files/folders in dir. Use –upgrade to replace existing packages in
>   dir with new versions.

And to use the package you can add `C:\Lib` to the `PYTHONPATH` env variable, this way you tell python that there are packages in a different folder than default

Comment: @ Wojtek Thanks. For me to document: `dos> SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;"C:\libPython"`